# What conditions apart from a bad request cause server to return 400 Bad Request? (IIS7)

Tags: windows, iis, iis-7

I have an ASP.NET website running on **IIS7** in **.NET v2.0** Integrated app pool.

For the last three days at nearly exactly 00:24:00 UTC my web server starts throwing out 400 Bad Request responses to nearly all (but not all) web requests. At around 03:00 - 03:10 the error clears and everything returns back to normal.

These are the same requests that come throughout the day and have done for years, they are not actually bad requests.

So my question is in what situation would **IIS 7** return Bad Request when the the request is not actually bad?

Some possibilities I'm looking into include:

- Loss of connection to database server
- Background process running using CPU / resources

Because the errors only last about 2 hours that leads me to think that it is some sort of background process running that is causing the error, that process finishing after about 2:30 hours but I don't see why I could be getting **HTTP 400 Bad Request** errors on the server.

Any help shining some light onto the possible nature of the 400 Bad Request error would be most appreciated. Keeping in mind that I am 100% sure that the request is valid.

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET application might be returning the 400 status code, rather than IIS.

Load conditions will not cause IIS to start sending bad request back, and normally a 5xx code would be returned by the server if the application failed or the database connection was down (though what is done when the database connection is down is entirely application-defined).

Comment: I don't think it is the application. In fact I see the error for static files too, for example in an exe file download.